# Why am I getting this weird character in PowerPoint on OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, character-encoding

I'm getting this odd character on OS X in PowerPoint.  It seems to be replacing '>' and other mathematical operators.  I'm guessing it's a missing font...

[image: character]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is a glyph from the [Last Resort font](http://www.unicode.org/charts/lastresort.html). This glyph stands generically for a [Private Use](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) code point. No characters are assigned to such code points in the Unicode Standard. Instead, there are allocated for use by private agreements between consenting parties. They have no meaning outside such agreements.

So it’s not just a matter of fonts, it’s about character data. The data might have been copied from somewhere, from a context where a font containing glyphs in Private Use codepoints is used. To make the data displayed the intended way, you would need to find and install that specific font. To make the data robust and portable, you would need to find a way to identify the intended characters as Unicode characters (they are probably defined in Unicode) and convert the data accordingly (and use *some* font that contains glyphs for the characters at their assigned code points).